# How to add IPV4 range to unmanaged server

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ubuntu-16.04, ip-address, ipv4

I am really inexperienced with Linux and networking.

I bought an unmanaged dedicated server running ubuntu 16.04. I am having problems with binding the ipv4/24 range with my dedicated server. How would I bind/add my IP range to my dedicated server?

Comment: Hate to say - by paying someone who HAS read all the docs. This quesiton will not solve a lot of followup questions magically. We only deal where with people that read the basic docs AND know how to provide all relevant information - for normal users, superuser.com is more likely to be the right palce. As per site rules. Note that you may be over your head with an unmanaged server, and the results of that are generally a hacked server.

Answer (score 0):

1. TomTom point has a lot of merit. Do consider seriously educating yourself on network management, or pay someone to do that for you. That being said, I'm all for people working through their problems towards proficiency, and using Server Fault to help with that, and messing with an unmanaged server is a great way to do that - just take into account that **you will get into a lot of trouble**.
2. Ubuntu 16.04 is pretty old is will go out of support next year. It is a Long Term Support release, but LTS in Ubuntu means 5 years. It would have been much better to start with a new 20.04 LTS installation, or even an 18.04 (giving you 3 years to figure it out before you have to upgrade). The fact that you got a new server with 16.04 is troubling - I would suggest you consider switching providers.
3. Make sure your provider is routing IPv4 range your bought to your server - this is out of your control and often where the line breaks. If you think you configured everything correctly and it still doesn't work - give your provider's support a call.
4. To set up the network interface, you'd want to add an entry to `/etc/network/interfaces` or create a new file with the entry in `/etc/network/interfaces.d`. See `man interfaces` for the full documentation or [this article](https://michael.mckinnon.id.au/2016/05/05/configuring-ubuntu-16-04-static-ip-address/) for a simple example.

You start by figure out your interface name - this should be easy by running `ip a` and find the correct interface, probably by looking for the other IP addresses that are supposed to already be attached to the correct interface. It should look like `ens<number>`.

As you are adding an additional IP address in addition to the existing one, you'd need to add an "alias interface" - think of it like a virtual interface card - it is bound to the same hardware but has additional configuration.

Then create the interface alias file (or edit the `interfaces` file) like in this example - I'm assuming the interface is named `ens5` and it will take the IP address `192.168.1.1`, and it will be the first alias:

```
iface ens5:1 inet static
  address 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.254
```

If you want to add more IP addresses to the same interface, you'd need to increment the alias ID - the part after the `:` in the interface name - for each new address.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I have a problem I searched up online and I did edit `etc/network/interfaces` and added another interface called enp1s0f0:0 then I inputted my IP address on there but it still didn't work. Do you have a clue on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: After editing the file you need to get it to load. The easiest way would be to restart the server. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes I did but it still didn't work